# vim imap trouble for automatically closing quotations

Tags: linux, vim

I managed to get auto closing braces and parentheses right:

```
imap { {<return><return>}<Esc>kcc
imap ( ()<Esc>i
```

However, quotation can't be written like parentheses. If I write it like this:

```
imap " ""<Esc>i
```

it goes into an infinite loop. Why does this happen?

I then wrote quotations like this:

```
imap " "<Esc>xPpi
```

This one too has a problem. It eats up a character to the left of insertion. I fiddled around with it, but could not work out how to get the mapping right. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
inoremap " ""<Esc>i
```

This way it will not apply mappings to the result of mapping (no resursion)